# Converting MultiLinestring to Linestring with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql, line, convert, multipart

I have a multiline string and want to convert it to a linestring in order to use some functions that only work with linestrings. I used `ST_Dump()` and got a collection of my geometries. If I merge them back together, I still get the multilinestring.

Should I get the Npoints and combine them together or something, in order to end up with a simple linestring? `ST_LineMerge()` also does not work on my multilinestring, it returns the same.

my example,

> MULTILINESTRING((-3.16420835153456 55.9269166007097,-3.164222
> 55.926918),(-3.1642070167833 55.9269296196706,-3.16421351659546 55.9268662214904),(-3.16421351659546 55.9268662214904,-3.16421636372824 55.9268384509897),(-3.16421636372824 55.9268384509897,-3.16422182573761 55.9267851753802),(-3.16422182573761 55.9267851753802,-3.16422870102352 55.926718114886),(-3.16422870102352 55.926718114886,-3.16423309121073 55.926675293667),(-3.16423309121073 55.926675293667,-3.16423565148822 55.9266503211093),(-3.16423565148822 55.9266503211093,-3.16424103159897 55.9265978443265),(-3.16424103159897 55.9265978443265,-3.16424680776317 55.9265415044985),(-3.16424680776317 55.9265415044985,-3.16425267254583 55.9264843002995),(-3.16425267254583 55.9264843002995,-3.16425541048045 55.9264575949012),(-3.16425541048045 55.9264575949012,-3.16426111146586 55.9264019883556),(-3.16426111146586 55.9264019883556,-3.1642667032531 55.9263474469124),(-3.1642667032531 55.9263474469124,-3.16426957768543 55.9263194101362),(-3.16426957768543 55.9263194101362,-3.16427488261739 55.9262676666359),(-3.16427488261739 55.9262676666359,-3.16428009893088 55.9262167875066),(-3.16428009893088 55.9262167875066,-3.164282741107 55.9261910161221),(-3.1642875546472 55.9261440655823,-3.164282741107 55.9261910161221),(-3.1642875546472 55.9261440655823,-3.16429466890915 55.9260746741522),(-3.16429466890915 55.9260746741522,-3.16430092974527 55.9260136069079),(-3.16430092974527 55.9260136069079,-3.16430822838418 55.9259424170929),(-3.16430822838418 55.9259424170929,-3.16431547242401 55.925871759829),(-3.16431547242401 55.925871759829,-3.16431448732505 55.9258328901507),(-3.16431770120536 55.9257327846001,-3.16431547242401 55.925871759829),(-3.164339 55.925777,-3.16431770120536 55.9257327846001))

Comment: Give us an example of these multilinestring you want to convert so we can test them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could also use [ST_SnapToGrid](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html) to sort of fix your data, but you'll need to play around with the parameters to get it right.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
    ST_LineMerge(
        ST_SnapToGrid(
            ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-3.16420835153456 55.9269166007097,-3.164222 55.926918),(-3.1642070167833 55.9269296196706,-3.16421351659546 55.9268662214904),(-3.16421351659546 55.9268662214904,-3.16421636372824 55.9268384509897),(-3.16421636372824 55.9268384509897,-3.16422182573761 55.9267851753802),(-3.16422182573761 55.9267851753802,-3.16422870102352 55.926718114886),(-3.16422870102352 55.926718114886,-3.16423309121073 55.926675293667),(-3.16423309121073 55.926675293667,-3.16423565148822 55.9266503211093),(-3.16423565148822 55.9266503211093,-3.16424103159897 55.9265978443265),(-3.16424103159897 55.9265978443265,-3.16424680776317 55.9265415044985),(-3.16424680776317 55.9265415044985,-3.16425267254583 55.9264843002995),(-3.16425267254583 55.9264843002995,-3.16425541048045 55.9264575949012),(-3.16425541048045 55.9264575949012,-3.16426111146586 55.9264019883556),(-3.16426111146586 55.9264019883556,-3.1642667032531 55.9263474469124),(-3.1642667032531 55.9263474469124,-3.16426957768543 55.9263194101362),(-3.16426957768543 55.9263194101362,-3.16427488261739 55.9262676666359),(-3.16427488261739 55.9262676666359,-3.16428009893088 55.9262167875066),(-3.16428009893088 55.9262167875066,-3.164282741107 55.9261910161221),(-3.1642875546472 55.9261440655823,-3.164282741107 55.9261910161221),(-3.1642875546472 55.9261440655823,-3.16429466890915 55.9260746741522),(-3.16429466890915 55.9260746741522,-3.16430092974527 55.9260136069079),(-3.16430092974527 55.9260136069079,-3.16430822838418 55.9259424170929),(-3.16430822838418 55.9259424170929,-3.16431547242401 55.925871759829),(-3.16431547242401 55.925871759829,-3.16431448732505 55.9258328901507),(-3.16431770120536 55.9257327846001,-3.16431547242401 55.925871759829),(-3.164339 55.925777,-3.16431770120536 55.9257327846001))'),
            0.001)
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 33):

Are you sure that all your MultiLines you want to convert [can be converted](http://postgis.org/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#OGC_Validity)?

> a simple geometry is one that has
>   no anomalous geometric points, such as self intersection or self
>   tangency and primarily refers to 0 or 1-dimensional geometries

Otherwise, `ST_LineMerge` should work:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_LineMerge(ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-29 -27,-30 -29.7,-36 -31,-45 -33),(-45 -33,-46 -32))')));
```

---

**UPDATE**

So this is the Multilinestring you provided. Looks valid from up here.:

[image]

But upon zooming in close for inspection you can clearly see this *cannot* be converted into a valid linestring.

[image] [image]

**VALID:**

[image] [image]

**INVALID:**

[image] [image]

But take a *VALID* subset of your points and it works just fine:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_LineMerge(ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-3.16422182573761 55.9267851753802,-3.16422870102352 55.926718114886),(-3.16422870102352 55.926718114886,-3.16423309121073 55.926675293667),(-3.16423309121073 55.926675293667,-3.16423565148822 55.9266503211093),(-3.16423565148822 55.9266503211093,-3.16424103159897 55.9265978443265),(-3.16424103159897 55.9265978443265,-3.16424680776317 55.9265415044985),(-3.16424680776317 55.9265415044985,-3.16425267254583 55.9264843002995),(-3.16425267254583 55.9264843002995,-3.16425541048045 55.9264575949012),(-3.16425541048045 55.9264575949012,-3.16426111146586 55.9264019883556),(-3.16426111146586 55.9264019883556,-3.1642667032531 55.9263474469124),(-3.1642667032531 55.9263474469124,-3.16426957768543 55.9263194101362),(-3.16426957768543 55.9263194101362,-3.16427488261739 55.9262676666359),(-3.16427488261739 55.9262676666359,-3.16428009893088 55.9262167875066))')));
```

Comment: This isn't actually correct.  LineStrings with self-intersections are still OGC-valid.  The reason the original MultiLineString can't be converted to a single LineString is that it contains 3 disjoint sets of connected vertices.

Comment: @dr_jts Right, So It's not that the LineString is invalid but the input is invalid. you cannot convert intersecting lines. So a valid input of linestrings is one without intersections.

Answer (score 2):

The query below creates a linestring from the multilinestring provied.

```sql
select st_astext(st_makeline(geom))
from ST_Dump(ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-3.16420835153456 55.9269166007097,-3.164222 55.926918),(-3.1642070167833 55.9269296196706,-3.16421351659546 55.9268662214904),
(-3.16421351659546 55.9268662214904,-3.16421636372824 55.9268384509897),(-3.16421636372824 55.9268384509897,-3.16422182573761 55.9267851753802),(-3.16422182573761 55.9267851753802,-3.16422870102352 55.926718114886),
(-3.16422870102352 55.926718114886,-3.16423309121073 55.926675293667),(-3.16423309121073 55.926675293667,-3.16423565148822 55.9266503211093),(-3.16423565148822 55.9266503211093,-3.16424103159897 55.9265978443265),
(-3.16424103159897 55.9265978443265,-3.16424680776317 55.9265415044985),(-3.16424680776317 55.9265415044985,-3.16425267254583 55.9264843002995),(-3.16425267254583 55.9264843002995,-3.16425541048045 55.9264575949012),
(-3.16425541048045 55.9264575949012,-3.16426111146586 55.9264019883556),(-3.16426111146586 55.9264019883556,-3.1642667032531 55.9263474469124),(-3.1642667032531 55.9263474469124,-3.16426957768543 55.9263194101362),
(-3.16426957768543 55.9263194101362,-3.16427488261739 55.9262676666359),(-3.16427488261739 55.9262676666359,-3.16428009893088 55.9262167875066),(-3.16428009893088 55.9262167875066,-3.164282741107 55.9261910161221),
(-3.1642875546472 55.9261440655823,-3.164282741107 55.9261910161221),(-3.1642875546472 55.9261440655823,-3.16429466890915 55.9260746741522),(-3.16429466890915 55.9260746741522,-3.16430092974527 55.9260136069079),
(-3.16430092974527 55.9260136069079,-3.16430822838418 55.9259424170929),(-3.16430822838418 55.9259424170929,-3.16431547242401 55.925871759829),(-3.16431547242401 55.925871759829,-3.16431448732505 55.9258328901507),
(-3.16431770120536 55.9257327846001,-3.16431547242401 55.925871759829),(-3.164339 55.925777,-3.16431770120536 55.9257327846001))'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using ST_SubDivide to break large geometries into smaller one after release 2.2.0.

I have validated and tested this on MultiLineString to break them in LineString.

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Subdivide.html

Answer (score 0):

-- for line discontinued

```
SELECT
  ST_ASTEXT(
    ST_LineFromMultiPoint(
      ST_AsEWKT(
        ST_Boundary(
          ST_GeomFromEWKT(
            'MULTILINESTRING(
              (-62.6222206786248 -17.5184605090261,-62.6180716059959 -17.5177886147977),
              (-62.6139802509635 -17.5171260672651,-62.6130233702558 -17.5169711115239)
            )'
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
```