# Check if point is inside unclosed linestring using POSTGIS ST Functions

Tags: postgis

I have a table with spatial data. This table contains a single record which is a unclosed linestring.

I calculated the Centroid of this geometry using query

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid("geom")) FROM "public"."ha_ground"
```

I got the output "POINT(73.8180699704927 18.6281375643436)"

My aim is to check if this point is inside the unclosed linestring

I used the following query

```
SELECT ST_Contains("geom",ST_GeomFromText('POINT(73.8180699704927 18.6281375643436)', 4326)) FROM "public"."ha_ground"
```

As We know Centroid of this geometry is inside the unclosed linestring.
But, This query returns false instead of true.

What is the possible reason for this.

And what is the solution to check if point is inside unclosed linestring

Comment: Can you not close the linestring and create a polygon from it -- which should then return something from contains?

Comment: I had also tried doing it using ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText("geom")), 5,'join=mitre mitre_limit=8.0') which gives polygon form of the geometry. But, it still not works.

Comment: 1) Please **edit** the question to add details 2) The "inside" of a line is "on" the line but not at an endpoint.

Comment: 3) The ST_Centroid function is [documented](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html) as **not** being restricted to the interior of the shape -- This refutes your assertion.

Comment: Ok but, I opened the geometry in QGIS and took a sample of latitude and longitude inside the geometry. But for that sample also its output is false.

Comment: Believe @John Barça and connect first end point to start point and build a polygon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the center point of MULTILINESTRING?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33618/how-to-find-the-center-point-of-multilinestring)

Comment: Consider also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76498/how-is-st-pointonsurface-calculated/76563#76563 in case your centroid is outside a convex polygon.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you have: a line and a disjoint point

[image]

First step you must do is to close the linestring but it is still a linestring and point is disjoint. All points which are not on the line are disjoint.

[image]

You must go on and convert the linearring into a polygon. Polygon does have a two-dimensional interior (area).

[image]

And only then you can get an answer to the question "Does a point locate inside a polygon which outer ring is is created by closing a linestring so that its end point is connected to its start point.